# Bitwise operations on integer act differently in DEBUG and RELEASE versions of project

Tags: c++

I use Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 64-bit.
I have these two methods:

```
void Node::setState(States state, bool value) {
    if (value) {
        states_ |= 1 << state;
    }
    else {
        states_ &= ~(1 << state);
    }
}

bool Node::getState(States state) {
    return (states_ & (1 << state)) != 0;
}
```

States enum:

```
enum States {
    UPDATABLE = 0x01, // Node data update.
    RENDERABLE = 0x02, // Node rendering on screen.
    TRANSFORMABLE = 0x04, // Position, rotation and scaling update.
    POSITION = 0x08, // Position update.
    ROTATION = 0x10, // Rotation update.
    SCALING = 0x20 // Scaling update.
};
```

States integer initialization:

```
states_(TRANSFORMABLE | RENDERABLE |
            UPDATABLE | POSITION | ROTATION | SCALING)
```

Now the problem is in this part of the code:

```
LOGI("SETTING SCALING FOR NODE: %s", node->getName().c_str());
node->setState(Node::SCALING, true);
if (node->getState(Node::SCALING)) {
    LOGI("NODE WILL BE UPDATED.");
}
else {
    LOGI("NODE WILL NOT BE UPDATED.");
}
```

On Debug mode I get "NODE WILL BE UPDATED", on Release - "NODE WILL NOT BE UPDATED".
What is causing this?

Comment: Start by showing *exactly* how `node` is allocated, or more importantly, where the address that pointer holds *comes from* ?

Comment: Node* node = new Node(); Is this what you asked for? I just add these nodes in node hierarchy. One node can have many child nodes. I hold on to the pointer to root node, so I could recursively reach all other nodes.

Comment: If your enums have values that are distinct bits, there's no reason to also shift by the values. Just replace `1 << state` with `state` in `setState`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SCALING` is a 32-bit signed integer with the value `0x20`.  You are left shifting `1` by `0x20` (32) bit positions.  that means you shifted it too far, resulting in undefined behavior.

Relevant quote from the standard:

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are ﬁlled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1× 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1× 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned.**

Comment: Can you give me an advise on how to change my methods to make them work the way I wanted?

Comment: @SMGhost - Just use `state` instead of `1 << state` in `setState`.

Comment: @SMGhost: Stop shifting.  Just use `if((state & SCALING) > 0);`

Answer (score 1):

The values of `States` are bit masks, not shift values.

Either change them to shift values:

```
enum States {
    UPDATABLE = 0, // Node data update.
    RENDERABLE = 1, // Node rendering on screen.
    TRANSFORMABLE = 2, // Position, rotation and scaling update.
    POSITION = 3, // Position update.
    ROTATION = 4, // Rotation update.
    SCALING = 5 // Scaling update.
};
```

and modify the initialisation of `states_` appropriately; or use them as masks:

```
void Node::setState(States state, bool value) {
    if (value) {
        states_ |= state;
    }
    else {
        states_ &= ~state;
    }
}

bool Node::getState(States state) {
    return (states_ & state) != 0;
}
```

Comment: The first won't work given the way OP is initializing `states_`.

Comment: @TedHopp: True, I didn't spot that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing states_ is a 32 bit integer.  Your implementation of setState and getState aren't doing what you expect.  Note that setState(SCALING) will shift 1 0x20 (= 32) bits to the left.  If you have a 32 bit integer, that's going to yield an undefined result (see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).  The code optimizer (probably the important difference in this case between the debug and release builds) is therefore free to do something different than the unoptimized code.

Given your definitions of States' values, setState should just be states_ |= state (or &= ~state).  Likewise, getState should just return states_ & state.